# What is the difference between correlation and mean absolute percentage error?

Tags: correlation, mape

So here is my question, I have to columns of data. One of them is a black box model's output, and the other one is my actual numbers.

The correlation between these two columns is 99%, but the MAPE is around 5%. How do I interpret this?

I know R2 means the model output is able to predict 100% of the variability in my actual numbers, but how does the MAPE of 5% come into play?

Do I just say the model's error is 5%? How do I use correlation to make any points about the model's output?

Comment: There is very little relationship between MAPE and $R^2$. For instance, if you simply add a constant $c>0$ to all predictions and all actuals, then the MAPE will decrease, but $R^2$ will stay constant. $R^2$ is actually rarely used in the forecasting community. See the proposed duplicate.

Comment: It does help, but I am still trying to understand how to interpret both metrics. I think I have a good understanding of MAPE, but when I think about correlation and I see 99%, should I believe that this is a good model? What does this 99% tell me about the accuracy of the model?

Comment: (1) The MAPE and the MSE/$R^2$ [are minimized by different functionals of the future distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352), so different point forecasts will be "good" for either one. You need to tailor your loss function to which functional you want to elicit. (2) Whether a given loss means that your method is "accurate" can't be decided in a vacuum, [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274317/1352).